# Exclude file from commit SERVERSIDE SVN

Tags: svn

I have a folder in project that I want to ignore from commit.Is there any way to exclude files/directories from commit at SERVER SIDE?

Comment: Do you mean that this folder is already in the repository, and you're not interested in it, or you don't want it added accidentally into Subversion? Or, do you want to prevent people from making changes in that folder? I can't help you unless you clarify what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the dir/file you don't want to commit --> Tortoise SVN --> Add to ignore list.

As to global setting you can set it via svn settings (right click in any white space -->Tortoise SVN --> settings-->General --> Global ignore pattern).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about **ignoring**, then using SVN 1.8 client can help. Subversion 1.8 clients understand [Repository Dictated Configuration](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config). You can use `svn:global-ignores` property to ignore **unversioned items**.